Flutter App on LAN Cannot Receive Response from Node.js API on WiFi (Ping Reaches API, No Response Back)
Problem:
I have a Flutter app running on a device connected to a LAN network, and a Node.js API running on a server connected to the same router via WiFi. There is no firewall enabled, and both devices can ping each other bi-directionally with no latency.
However, when trying to make a ping request from my Flutter app to the Node.js API, the ping request reaches the API, but the response does not come back to the Flutter app.
Network Setup:

Flutter Device: Connected to LAN.
Server (Node.js API): Connected to WiFi.
Both devices are on the same router and can communicate with each other.
No firewall is enabled on either device.
Ping works both ways with no latency.

Steps to Reproduce:
In Postman (from Flutter device): The ping request reaches the Node.js API successfully.
The response is not received back from the API.
In Flutter App: I am using Dio to send a GET request to the /ping endpoint of the API.

Flutter code
Future<bool> testConnectivity() async {
  Logger.log('DIO TEST CONNECTION.', level: LogLevel.debug);
  try {
    final response = await _dio.get('/ping');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Logger.log('DIO TEST SUCCESSFUL.', level: LogLevel.debug);
      return true;
    }
    Logger.log('DIO TEST FAILURE WITH STATUS CODE ${response.statusCode}.',
        level: LogLevel.error);
    return false;
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('GENERAL EXCEPTION: ${e.toString().toUpperCase()}.',
        level: LogLevel.error);
    return false;
  }
}

Node JS Code
router.get("/ping", (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Ping endpoint hit at ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
    res.status(200).json({ status: "success", message: "pong" });
});

Dio Logs
DIO TEST CONNECTION.
Dio Log: *** Request ***
Dio Log: uri: http://192.168.10.15:3000/ping
Dio Log: method: GET
Dio Log: responseType: ResponseType.json
Dio Log: connectTimeout: 0:00:15.000000
Dio Log: sendTimeout: 0:00:15.000000
Dio Log: receiveTimeout: 0:00:30.000000
Dio Log: data: null
Dio Log: *** DioException ***
Dio Log: uri: http://192.168.10.15:3000/ping
Dio Log: DioException [connection timeout]: The request connection took longer than 0:00:15.000000 and it was aborted. 



Ping endpoint hit at 2024-11-22T04:47:06.179Z
Response sent at 2024-11-22T04:47:06.190Z
CLIENT CONNECTED: IP ADDRESS: 192.168.10.24 | HOSTNAME: 192.168.10.24


You have a routing / network / router firewall issue if even with postman you do not received an answer. You could try to plug both device with a direct cable, setup their IP and check if it works. If yes, the router is probably the cause of the issue.
Try to tracert / traceroute between the two devices, and check their network interfaces confirgurations
